# Make sanitizing function traverse potentially nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, post, sanitization

I have the following code blocks in a PHP form-handler:

```
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    
    return $data;
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

I am modifying my form to now include checkbox groups:

eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phone_prefs[]" value="prefer_home">
<input type="checkbox" name="phone_prefs[]" value="prefer_cell">
<input type="checkbox" name="phone_prefs[]" value="prefer_work">
etc.
```

Because of this code I now have arrays in my _POST variables rather than just strings.

Am I correct in thinking that my `filter()` function the will not actually sanitize arrays properly? What changes do I need to make to my `filter()` function to make sure the arrays for the checkboxes are sanitized completely and not an easy target for SQL injection attacks?

Comment: You don't need to combine **htmlentities** and **strip_tags**.

Comment: Nor do you need to use htmlentities for filtering input.  Use htmlentities for escaping content for HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is pretty good, but if you make it recursive it'll crawl nested arrays for you

```
function filter(&$array) {
    $clean = array();
    foreach($array as $key => &$value ) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            filter($value);
        } else {
            $value = trim(strip_tags($value));
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $data = stripslashes($value);
            }
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }
}

filter($_POST); # filters $_POST and any nested arrays by reference
```

Edit: Leave out `htmlentities()`. If you need it, then use it when outputting the values - not when getting them as input.

Answer (score 4):

As for the sql injection, I would switch to PDO using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

You can use a simple `is_array()` on your values to check for an array and then loop through it. You are correct, as it is, your `filter` function will not handle arrays correctly.

**Edit:** If you use PDO and a prepared statement, you don´t need `mysql_real_escape_string` anymore. `strip_tags`, `htmlentities` and `trim` are also not needed to store the information safely in a database, they are needed when you output information to the browser (`trim` not of course...), although `htmlspecialchars` would be sufficient for that. It´s always better to prepare your information / output correctly for the medium you are outputting to at that moment.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that with prepared statements, escaping is no longer required.

Comment: Strongly recommend the following slide series on SQL injection http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies by StackOverflow member Bill Karwin.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_walk_recursive($array,function(&$item){
     $item=mysql_real_escape_string($item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a foreach on the $_POST which only loops once, using the Array and handling it like a string.

Try using:

```
foreach($_POST['phone_prefs'] as $key => $value)
```

EDIT:

I believe I misunderstood your question:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    if (is_array($value))
        foreach($_POST[$key] as $key2 => $value2)
            /* Setting stuff */
    else /* Setting same stuff */
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sanitizing the input manually, use **always** *prepared statements* with *placeholders*. That will transparently pass the input to the database in such a way that it does not need to be escaped and thus is not vulnerable to SQL injection. This is the best current practice.

See the following for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

I use this on various sites I have created:

```
public function clean($dirty) {
    if (!is_array($dirty)) {
        $dirty  = ereg_replace("[\'\")(;|`,<>]", "", $dirty);
        $dirty  = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($dirty));
        $clean  = stripslashes($dirty);
        return $clean;
    }
    $clean      = array();
    foreach ($dirty as $p => $data) {
        $data   = ereg_replace("[\'\")(;|`,<>]", "", $data);
        $data   = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($data));
        $data   = stripslashes($data);
        $clean[$p] = $data;
    }
    return $clean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql_real_escape_string means a MySQL connection is required before using the function, which is not best convenient. I used to use a work around in that case :

```
function real_escape_string($aQuery) {
    if (!is_string($aQuery)) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return strtr($aQuery, array( "\x00" => '\x00', "\n" => '\n', "\r" => '\r', '\\' => '\\\\', "'" => "\'", '"' => '\"', "\x1a" => '\x1a' ));
    }
}
```

But definitely, the best is to use PDO prepared statement instead of mysql. You will enjoy it.