# How to multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to retrieve data (the name in this case) from two tables and display them into a table. The columns are the same in both of the tables.

Can I do something like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select table1.name, table2.name 
                      from table1, table2 where   id='$pid'");
```

Comment: I try it but an error shows up : Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: table1.id='$pid'"); since your using multiple table dont let your column name be ambiguous.. always put their table name and dot before column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select table1.name as 'table1_name', table2.name as 'table2_name' from table1, table2 where table1.id='$pid' and table2.id='$pid'");
```

Also, note that if the value of `$pid` is coming from an outside source, you should really prepare the data before you query it against the server. You can create your own [filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904192/sanitizing-array-values-before-mysql-inserts) or you can utilize the [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) function that does the work for you through data binding.

Comment: When i used that I only get the data from table 2. My point is when for example I search a movie, and i select to buy two movies from two different tables(table1,table2) and I want the selected movies to be displayed for example in a table. I don't know how much I explain, but I hope you got've the point.

Comment: @Isabella: I don't really understand what you are asking here. I think the reason why you only got the name for `table2` was because of the result had a name conflict because both were called name. I edited the original query to use column aliases. This should resolve the conflict. Now you will reference the result by the alias name like `$row->table1_name`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

change column's name like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select t1.name name1, t2.name name2 
                      from table1 t1, table2 t2 
                      where t1.id=t2.id and t1.id='$pid'");
```